# How to create a method to calculate and set the interval of a chart

Tags: graph, flex3, intervals

I am learning flex. And I need your help, I want to create a method to calculate the interval value of the vertical axis depending on the values of the "dataProvider".

```
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis labelFunction="usageColumnSerieLabelFn" interval="0.0001"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>
```

Like you see, in that piece of code, I am hardcoding the interval. like I said, I want your help in order to create a new method to calculate and set this value.

I believe, If we took the greater value in the "dataProvider" and then set this value (greater Value + 0.1) to the interval. Will do the trick. But I dont know how to set the properties outside the mx:LinearAxis component.

I made this example, please if you have time, please give me a hand.

Regards

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- charts/BasicColumn.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
     import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
     import mx.charts.HitData;

    import mx.formatters.SwitchSymbolFormatter;
    import mx.charts.series.items.LineSeriesItem;
    import mx.charts.HitData;
    import mx.formatters.NumberFormatter;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.effects.easing.Bounce;
    import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

     private var decimalFormatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();

     [Bindable]
     public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {hour:"00",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"01",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"02",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"03",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"04",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"05",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"06",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"07",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"08",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"09",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"10",  Expenses:0.00009},
        {hour:"11",  Expenses:0.00009},
        {hour:"12",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"13",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"14",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"15",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"16",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"17",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"18",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"19",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"20",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"21",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"22",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"23",  Expenses:0.00009}
     ]);

     private function customDataTipFunc(item:HitData):String{

        decimalFormatter.precision = 4;
        var dataTip:String = "";

        dataTip += "<B>kWh</B>\n";
        dataTip += item.item.hour + "\n";

        if (item.item.Expenses == 0) {
            dataTip += decimalFormatter.format(item.item.Expenses).toString() + " kWh";
        } else {
            if(item.item.Expenses < 0.0001) {
                dataTip += "&lt;0.0001 kWh";    
            } else {
                dataTip += decimalFormatter.format(item.item.Expenses).toString() + " kWh";
            }
        }

        return dataTip;
    }

    public function axisLabelFn(cat:Object,pcat:Object,ax:LinearAxis):String{
                var nf1:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
                nf1.useThousandsSeparator = true;
                nf1.precision = 4;

                var tempNumber:Number = Number(cat.toString());
                var out:String = ""

                if (tempNumber == 0) {
                    out = nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";
                }else {
                    if (tempNumber < 0.0001) {
                        out = "&lt;" + nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";    
                    } else {
                        out = nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";
                    }   
                }

                //return nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";
                return out;
    }

  ]]></mx:Script>
  <mx:Panel title="Column Chart Kwh" width="1200">
     <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" showDataTips="true" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="{expenses}" minHeight="150" dataTipFunction="customDataTipFunc">
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
           <mx:CategoryAxis 
                dataProvider="{expenses}" 
                categoryField="hour"
           />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis labelFunction="axisLabelFn" interval="0.0001"/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:series>
           <mx:ColumnSeries 
                xField="hour" 
                yField="Expenses" 
                displayName="Kwh"
           />
        </mx:series>
     </mx:ColumnChart>
     <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: If you do not want this to be done outside of the linear axis, then extend the linearaxis and set it there, use this customcomponent in place of the linear axis?

Comment: hmm.. I want to do this, outside of the linear axis. In a different function. I am reading about "ho to extend the linearaxis". But I am not sure how to do it. Thanks for the reply, but if you can give me an example, will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Zeus for your words. I tried a few things, and this is the final "solution".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- charts/BasicColumn.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
     creationComplete="calculateInterval()">
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
     import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
     import mx.charts.HitData;

    import mx.formatters.SwitchSymbolFormatter;
    import mx.charts.series.items.LineSeriesItem;
    import mx.charts.HitData;
    import mx.formatters.NumberFormatter;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.effects.easing.Bounce;
    import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

     private var decimalFormatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();


     [Bindable]
     public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {hour:"00",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"01",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"02",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"03",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"04",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"05",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"06",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"07",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"08",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"09",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"10",  Expenses:0.00009},
        {hour:"11",  Expenses:0.00009},
        {hour:"12",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"13",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"14",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"15",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"16",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"17",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"18",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"19",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"20",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"21",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"22",  Expenses:0.0},
        {hour:"23",  Expenses:0.00009}
     ]);


     public function calculateInterval():void{
        var maxValue:Number = 0;
        for ( var x:int = 0; x < expenses.length; ++x ) {            
             if (maxValue < expenses.getItemAt(x).Expenses){
                maxValue = expenses.getItemAt(x).Expenses;
             }
        }
        MyLinearAxis.interval = maxValue + 0.0001;

    }

     private function customDataTipFunc(item:HitData):String{

        decimalFormatter.precision = 4;
        var dataTip:String = "";

        dataTip += "<B>kWh</B>\n";
        dataTip += item.item.hour + "\n";

        if (item.item.Expenses == 0) {
            dataTip += decimalFormatter.format(item.item.Expenses).toString() + " kWh";
        } else {
            if(item.item.Expenses < 0.0001) {
                dataTip += "&lt;0.0001 kWh";    
            } else {
                dataTip += decimalFormatter.format(item.item.Expenses).toString() + " kWh";
            }
        }

        return dataTip;
    }

    public function axisLabelFn(cat:Object,pcat:Object,ax:LinearAxis):String{

                var nf1:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
                nf1.useThousandsSeparator = true;
                nf1.precision = 4;

                var tempNumber:Number = Number(cat.toString());
                var out:String = ""

                if (tempNumber == 0) {
                    out = nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";
                }else {
                    if (tempNumber < 0.0001) {
                        out = "&lt;" + nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";    
                    } else {
                        out = nf1.format(cat) + " kWh";
                    }   
                }

                return out;
    }

  ]]></mx:Script>
  <mx:Panel title="Column Chart Kwh" width="1200">
     <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" showDataTips="true" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="{expenses}" minHeight="150" dataTipFunction="customDataTipFunc">
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
           <mx:CategoryAxis 
                dataProvider="{expenses}" 
                categoryField="hour"
           />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="MyLinearAxis" labelFunction="axisLabelFn" />
        </mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:series>
           <mx:ColumnSeries 
                xField="hour" 
                yField="Expenses" 
                displayName="Kwh"
           />
        </mx:series>
     </mx:ColumnChart>
     <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Like you see, I am calling the function "calculateInterval()" with the call method "creationComplete" in the mx:Application. In this method I am calculating the interval and setting an offset to the max value in the dataprovider.

I also set an id to the linearAxis, with this ID I set the interval.

If you think in a better aproach, let me know please.

Regards.